# crash in calloc

Tags: gcc, crash, openmp, calloc

I'm trying to debug a program I wrote. I ran it inside `gdb` and I managed to catch a `SIGABRT` from inside `calloc()`. I'm completely confused about how this can arise. Can it be a bug in `gcc` or even `libc`??

More details: My program uses OpenMP. I ran it through `valgrind` in single-threaded mode with no errors. I also use `mmap()` to load a 40GB file, but I doubt that is relevant. Inside `gdb`, I'm running with 30 threads. Several identical runs (same input&CL) finished correctly, until the problematic one that I caught. On the surface this suggests there might be a race condition of some type. However, the `SIGABRT` comes from `calloc()` which is out of my control. Here is some relevant `gdb` output:

```
(gdb) info threads
[...]
  17 Thread 0x7fffec450700 (LWP 73455)  0x00007ffff6b3ce00 in __read_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  16 Thread 0x7fffece51700 (LWP 73454)  _mm_slli_si128 (genome=<value optimized out>, goff=<value optimized out>, glen=50, read=<value optimized out>, rlen=36, genome_ls=<value optimized out>, initbp=-1, is_rna=false) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/include/emmintrin.h:1155
  14 Thread 0x7fffee253700 (LWP 73452)  0x000000000041183e in _mm_prefetch (re=0x7fff291c0f10, st=1, options=0x632014) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/include/xmmintrin.h:1193
  13 Thread 0x7fffeec54700 (LWP 73451)  0x00007ffff6ae5c84 in __memset_sse2 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  12 Thread 0x7fffef655700 (LWP 73450)  _mm_cmpeq_epi16 (genome=<value optimized out>, goff=<value optimized out>, glen=33, read=<value optimized out>, rlen=24, genome_ls=<value optimized out>, initbp=-1, is_rna=false) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/include/emmintrin.h:1263
* 11 Thread 0x7ffff0056700 (LWP 73449)  0x00007ffff6a948a5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  10 Thread 0x7ffff0a57700 (LWP 73448)  _mm_sub_epi16 (genome=<value optimized out>, goff=<value optimized out>, glen=36, read=<value optimized out>, rlen=26, genome_ls=<value optimized out>, initbp=-1, is_rna=false) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/include/emmintrin.h:1046
  5 Thread 0x7ffff3c5c700 (LWP 73443)  0x000000000041183e in _mm_prefetch (re=0x7fff28615010, st=1, options=0x632014) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/include/xmmintrin.h:1193
  2 Thread 0x7ffff5a5f700 (LWP 73440)  0x000000000041e4cd in _mm_max_epi16 (genome=<value optimized out>, goff=<value optimized out>, glen=29, read=<value optimized out>, rlen=21, genome_ls=<value optimized out>, initbp=-1, is_rna=false) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/include/emmintrin.h:1331
  1 Thread 0x7ffff7fdcae0 (LWP 73437)  0x00007ffff6ae5cff in __memset_sse2 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
[...]
(gdb) thread 11
[Switching to thread 11 (Thread 0x7ffff0056700 (LWP 73449))]#0  0x00007ffff6a948a5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6a948a5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6a96085 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff6ad1fe7 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff6ad7916 in malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff6adb79f in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff6adbdd6 in calloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#6  0x000000000040e87f in my_calloc (re=0x7fff2867ef10, st=0, options=0x632020) at gmapper/../gmapper/../common/my-alloc.h:286
#7  read_get_hit_list_per_strand (re=0x7fff2867ef10, st=0, options=0x632020) at gmapper/mapping.c:1046
#8  0x000000000041308a in read_get_hit_list (re=<value optimized out>, options=0x632010, n_options=1) at gmapper/mapping.c:1239
#9  handle_read (re=<value optimized out>, options=0x632010, n_options=1) at gmapper/mapping.c:1806
#10 0x0000000000404f35 in launch_scan_threads (.omp_data_i=<value optimized out>) at gmapper/gmapper.c:557
#11 0x00007ffff7230502 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1
#12 0x00007ffff6dfc851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#13 0x00007ffff6b4a11d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) f 6   
#6  0x000000000040e87f in my_calloc (re=0x7fff2867ef10, st=0, options=0x632020) at gmapper/../gmapper/../common/my-alloc.h:286
286         res = calloc(size, 1);
(gdb) p size
$2 = 814080
(gdb)
```

The function `my_calloc()` is just a wrapper, but the problem is not in there, as the real `calloc()` call looks legit. These are the limits set in the shell:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 2067285
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The program is not out of memory, it's using 41GB on a machine with 256GB available:

```
$ top -b -n 1 | grep gmapper
 73437 user      20   0 41.5g  16g  15g T  0.0  6.6  55:17.24 gmapper-ls
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        258437     195567      62869          0         82     189677
-/+ buffers/cache:       5807     252629
Swap:            0          0          0
```

I compiled using `g++ (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)`, with flags `-g -O2 -DNDEBUG -mmmx -msse -msse2 -fopenmp -Wall -Wno-deprecated -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS`.

*Edit*: The detailed error message I get is below. I truncated it, lines not shown are similar to the last 5.

```
*** glibc detected *** /tmp/t/gmapper-ls: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000009447380 ***
*** glibc detected *** /tmp/t/gmapper-ls: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000009447380 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x75916)[0x7ffff6ad7916]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x75916)[0x7ffff6ad7916]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7979f)[0x7ffff6adb79f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7979f)[0x7ffff6adb79f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x71)[0x7ffff6adc141]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_calloc+0xc6)[0x7ffff6adbdd6]
/usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1(+0x8502)[0x7ffff7230502]
/usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1(+0x8502)[0x7ffff7230502]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7ffff6b4a11d]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7851)[0x7ffff6dfc851]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7ffff6b4a11d]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00430000 r-xp 00000000 00:14 927268870                          /tmp/t/gmapper
00630000-00631000 rw-p 00030000 00:14 927268870                          /tmp/t/gmapper
00631000-2f461000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f749d9be000-7f7e2053b000 r--p 00000000 00:0f 1278724                    /dev/shm/hg19-ls
7fff24000000-7fff2727a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff2727a000-7fff28000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff285ce000-7fff2c000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff2c000000-7fff2f547000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff2f547000-7fff30000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
[...]
```

*Edit2*: I added thread info for all the threads which are stopped in what seem to be "nontrivial" places (10/30).

Comment: Please include your source code too!

Comment: What error message do you get from glibc?

Comment: @BobKaufman: The source code is at https://github.com/compbio-UofT/shrimp. However it's quite large, and I don't really expect somebody else to read through it all. If you have more specific questions I can try to answer those.

Comment: @HristoIliev: I added the error message printed before the `gdb` prompt. Is this the one you needed from `glibc`?

Comment: I would suggest that you run your code with Intel Thread Checker if available (I think you can download it and obtain a trial license) or with Sun Thread Analyzer (part of Oracle Solaris Studio 12 for Linux and still free). Compile without optimisations and with debug info for both tools (warning: changing opt. level can change program behaviour and the bug might disappear). Looks like data race to me.

Comment: I was going to try `helgrind`, for which I have to recompile `gcc` to disable futexes (and turn OpenMP into PThreads), but then I ran into missing deps for which I'll wait for sysadmins on Monday. I'll look into the tools you mention, too. (But race in `libc`?) In the meantime the process just sits there stopped, inside gdb, so I can look inside, but I don't know what for exactly. Unfortunately it seems like libc symbols aren't loaded.

Comment: I don't believe the race is in glibc but rather in the user code.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your GCC version is quite old. Current GCC is 4.7.2

For debugging purpose, you might compile with less optimization: instead of using `-g -O2 -NDEBUG -mmmx -msse -msse2 -fopenmp -Wall` just use `-g -Wall`.

<sup>compiling with less optimization makes the `gdb` debugger more happy</sup>

Then, use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and `gdb` to debug your program.

Comment: The node is running CentOS 6.3, which is up to date as far as I can tell (not being the admin). Hence the older `gcc`. So you really think it's a `gcc` problem? For `valgrind` I had compiled with the same flags minus `-O2 -NDEBUG`. However, the fact that several runs completed just fine suggests this has to do with threading, which is not caught by single-threaded `valgrind`. I haven't tried removing any of the other flags, will do that next.